# How do I make user controls for both ListView and ListViewItem work with each other?

Tags: wpf, listview, user-controls, listviewitem

I have all the styling, triggers, etc. down for `ListView` and `ListViewItem`, and I want to turn them into user controls. How do I make sure that these two "match up" with each other, so that `MyListView` accepts `MyListViewItem`s as content? Also, considering that I must end the `ListView` tag by the end of the user control XAML file, I am not sure how I would add items to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them to be reusable with different data sets, especially through binding, you should stay away from `UserControls` and just make custom controls derived from the original types. In that case you create a standalone `MyListView.cs` and `MyListViewItem.cs` and all of the XAML for the controls goes into default Styles (usually also containing a `ControlTemplate`) in `Themes/Generic.xaml`. You can see an example of this setup by just adding a WPF Custom Control to your WPF project from Add New Item.

Once you've created the .cs files for your custom controls you just need to override a few methods from the base `ItemsControl` to use `MyListViewItem` as the item container control. The `ListView` would end up like this:

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    static MyListView()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyListView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyListView)));
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new MyListViewItem();
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return item is MyListViewItem;
    }
}
```

You can now use your custom `MyListView` exactly as you would a normal `ListView`, including binding to `ItemsSource`.

Comment: This is for a navigation bar that will always be present on the left side of the window, so I imagine that data sets will be unlikely. Is it still recommended to avoid using a User Control?

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance *should* take care of that for you. In other words, if you have two user controls, the first one with a basic element of ListView (not UserControl) and the other of ListViewItem (again, not UserControl), and you make sure they extend ListView and ListViewItem respectively in the .cs code, the following should work equally:

```
ListView lv = new ListView();
lv.Items.Add(new ListViewItem());
```

or

```
MyListView mlv = new MyListView();
mlv.Items.Add(new myListViewItem()); //If your myListView extends ListView, and myListViewItem extends ListViewItem in your user control files, of course
```

In case you are looking for a XAML solution, you should import your namespace at the top

```
xmlns:myControls="WhateverYourNamespaceAndAssemblyAre"
```

and on you page/window/whatever

```
<myControls:myListView>
    <myControls:myListViewItem/>
    <myControls:myListViewItem/>
</myControls:myListView>
```